# flatten nested array php?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Ok taken the following:

```
    array(80) {
      ["_edit_lock"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "1405955175:1"
      }
      ["_edit_last"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      ["slide_template"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "default"
      }
      ["pyre_video"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["pyre_full_width"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
   }
```

how do I flatten this to :

```
array(80) {
  ["_edit_lock"]=>  string(12) "1405955175:1"
  ["_edit_last"]=>  string(1) "1"
  ["slide_template"]=>  string(7) "default"
  ["pyre_video"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["pyre_full_width"]=>   string(2) "no"
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$res = array();

foreach ($src_array as $key => $value) {
  $res[$key] = $value[0];
}

var_dump($res);
?>
```

Comment: which is quicker? array_map or for each?

Comment: For an 80 element array, there would be no noticeable difference.

Comment: I was just curious, if it was used on a larger array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$flattened = array_map(function($arr){return $arr[0];}, $your_array);
```

Comment: which is quicker? array_map or for each?

Comment: @vimes1984 Why bother such micro level optimization?

Comment: @vimes1984 the time required to write the tests to judge which is faster will waste more time than using the faster method will ever save. Hell, I don't think it will even cover writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about the following?

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
     'first' => array('blabla'),
     'second' => array('blabla'),
);

foreach($myArray as $key => $layer) {
     if(is_array($layer)) {
          $myArray[$key] = $layer[key($myArray)];
     } else { continue; }
}
```